# using where clause with sorted(always) non index cloumn

Tags: php, mysql

I create a table whose one non-index column  is always sorted and i want to get some results using Where(on sorted column ) clause.but Where clause goes through all the records for results.How to take result efficiently(in terms of time) using query on sorted column.or Is there is any way where don't go through all the records and use the fact column is sorted.
**column cannot be make any type of key**

Comment: Why can't the column use a key?

Comment: because it is not eligible for for any key

Comment: Without indexes, your table is simply an unordered collection of rows; as such the where clause must scan the entire table.

Comment: is it possible to apply binary search on sorted  column

Comment: as Chris said, without an index MySQL can't know that your column is ordered and will not do a binary search, nor can you force it to do one, it just wasn't built that way. You should put an index on it (all columns are eligible for an index) and then you'll be able to have mysql automatically do a binary search on that column as long as that is the only column in your where clause.